# Router access point

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I would like to use a router with a pc so,without any internet connection,I can make it detectable by other devices(it must be detectable wirelessly).Once these devices connect,they will be able to recieve files from my PC.I don't wish to use a second router for this.I must mention that the router in question is not connected to anything(I took it out of a box).I surfed the internet in order to find a tutorial on this,but I found information about wi fi repeaters and access points plugged to a main router.I just want to use this router as a means of transmitting files wirelessly to other devices without internet connection.How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If it is just a simple "office/home" table-top router, just plug in whatever wired devices you have to the LAN ports and it might already work like that. However, (some of) the ethernet ports might have been configured not to let connected devices see each other so check the settings of the router (see the manual for instructions how to do that since it is device specific). If the router also is a wireless access point I'd bet it will forward traffic by default between the wireless and wired devices. Have you tried any of this yet?

Answer (score 0):

you have first to reconfigure the router to work as switch,try first connecting all the devices on the router without connecting any cable to the internet port and make sure all have the same IP Sub-net if this didn't work check the below link.

http://www.howtogeek.com/174419/how-to-reuse-your-old-wi-fi-router-as-a-network-switch/

Comment: I suppose perhaps you mean reconfigure it as JUST a switch. Since when it runs as a router the built in switch still does switching.

Comment: yes, that was what i understood from the question